# Debug assertion failure of OpenCV function "Split"&"Merge"

Tags: c++, opencv

The codes are as follows

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
bool MultiBlending();
int main()
{
    if (MultiBlending())
    cout << "Program Running Success." << endl;
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}

bool MultiBlending()
{
    vector<Mat> Channels;
    Mat srcImage1 = imread("dota_jugg.jpg");
    Mat dotaLogo = imread("dota_logo.jpg", 0);
    Mat imgROI,
    dstImage,
    srcImage2;

    //Process begins
    split(srcImage1, Channels);

    //Blue channel
    Mat blueChannel;
    blueChannel = Channels.at(0);

    //Define ROI
    imgROI = blueChannel(Rect(500, 250, dotaLogo.cols, dotaLogo.rows));

    //Blend
    addWeighted(imgROI, 1.0, dotaLogo, 0.5, 0, imgROI);

    //Merge
    merge(Channels, dstImage);

    //Display
    imshow("Blue Blending", dstImage);

    return true;
}
```

This is just a simple program and it should be working properly. But I kept receiving the result "Debug Assertion Failed"
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uwIr.png)

After applying the "step over" method, I found that the error occurred after calling the function "MultiBlending". To be more specific, after the expression "return true". And I've tried putting all the stuff in the function into the main function. Then I received the same result, which occurred after the expression "return 0" in the main function.

So I've been thinking maybe there is something to do with memory releasing. But I don't know where and how?

Comment: This works as expected for me. Please provide the error message (not a useless screenshot). Also post the images you're using.

Answer (score 0):

For merge you need:

```
merge(Channels,3, dstImage);
```

and I am not sure but I think you need this while declaration of channels:

```
vector<Mat> Channels(3);
```